# Browserify Window Function Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, browserify

So I had this strange occurrence with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) where even if my functions were made to function in the global scope, the console still shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (signUp.html:86)
```

As you can see, I made a testing script for this bellow:

Pre-Browserify Build

```
Window.testing = function()
{
    console.log('this executed');
}
```

and it is yet to work despite it being in the global scope. Take this with 100% certainty also that the correct directory and file is included into the html. I am using the function within the html as follows:

```
        <div class="col-md-12 section-heading text-center to-animate">
                        
                                
            <button onclick="testing()">Generate Key For a New Wallet<button>
            <br>

<!---Etc.Etc.Etc.--->
```

I am confused? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `window` instead of`Window`

Comment: I tried this the first time and it said it was undefined, but it worked this time wth. Thank you

Comment: Yea in my real file it still doesn't work. But I think it is because I am attempting to use libraries browserify doesnt work with